# can we install Sharepoint 2013 with 2012 server but the Domain controller and exchange is 2003

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

we are planning to start using sharepoint 2013 foundation in our environment but our DC and exchange are both 2003, we dont want to upgrade them now but we are planning to buy new 2012 server join it to 2003 DC as a client and install sharepoint 2013 foundation.

will it work ? 
there will be any issues with our DC or exchange if we do this ? 
exchange 2003 will support sharepoint integration ?

i am scare we might get some issues with exchange or DC after doing this or its ok and i can just load everything on 2012 server which is client of DC 2003 and will be running our sharepoint 2013.

Help please once i get green signal will fire up the installation. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will work.

SharePoint does not have a requirement for Active Directory to be a greater version than 2003 (I'm assuming the domain functional level and farm functional level in your case are at least 2003), and the same goes for Exchange for incoming (which sends to the IIS SMTP service) or outgoing email.

You won't be able to make use of the Exchange integration that is available only for Exchange 2013 like eDiscovery.

Comment: Thanks buddy , much appreciated .. now i will setup the environment for sharepoint 2013 .. :)